# immediately notification about message java + js

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, messaging

I have no expirience with messaging between js + java and sorry for my english. I want to do immediately notification when message was received like in most popular social nets like Facebook, vk.com e.t.c. What best solution for this implementation? At the moment i want to use websocket connection for messaging while user working on the site. For example, all users will be had sessions and after send of message, user will be detected on the server by his session  and he will get this message. Sorry for my english but i want to know best solution for this implementation and i don't found any idea so these only my thinking. Please who had expirience with these, please write your ideas about it.

Comment: If you're only pushing messages to the clients (one way) you can also use Server-Sent-Events. Other than that, your question is too vague to give an answer to.

Comment: Thank you man, i think it's really what i want